# Не могу установить Pygame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

Прописываю в консоль

```
iMac-Nikita:~ nikita$ pip3 install pygame
Requirement already satisfied: pygame in ./Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages (2.0.1)
iMac-Nikita:~ nikita$ python3 -m pygame.examples.aliens
pygame 2.0.1 (SDL 2.0.14, Python 3.8.8)
Hello from the pygame community. https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html
iMac-Nikita:~ nikita$
```

После этого запускается aliens, игра полностью работает.
После этого захожу в IDLE и прописываю

```
>>> import pygame
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    import pygame
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pygame'
```

Кто-то может подсказать почему?

Comment: например, в консоли один питон, а idle запускается для другого. Что написано в самой верхней строчке idle после запуска (там где версия языка)?

Comment: Там написанно 3.8.8.

Comment: Попробуй перелезть с idle на тот же pycharm. Но в pycharm'е надо прописывать install нужных модулей для каждого проекта по отдельности через консоль pycharm'а (у него есть снизу вкладки по типу run console и.т.п. Открываешь проект, в проекте открываешь вкладку console и там все pip'ы прописываешь нужные.)

Comment: к сожалению с pycharm у меня отдельная проблема, и ее скорее всего будет еще сложнее решить чем эту

Comment: а другие установленные модули в idle загружаются?

Comment: да, остальные библиотеки загружаются и работают правильно

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема в том, что установочные файлы все для 32 бит.
Попробуй устоновить pygame64
[https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pygame](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#pygame)

или
https://www.pygame.org/wiki/macintosh